# Cannot ping ubuntu server by hostname - can only ping by IP

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, hostname

I have an unbuntu 9.10 server and have set the hostname to "fileserver"  When I try to ping fileserver from a client machine it doesn't find it, however I can ping by the IP my router assigns it.  I have tried changing the ip in /etc/hosts from this:

```
127.0.0.1    fileserver
```

to this:

```
192.168.1.109    fileserver
```

which is the ip being assigned.  I had a previous install of this server and i had no issues with this - only difference in this install is i did not select any of the options such as LAMP, OpenSSH, etc during the install process.  I can access the machine fine by ip using PuTTY.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If it is the case that you're putting that entry in the **server**'s hosts file: The hosts file is changed on the client side, not the server side. When a computer tries to resolve a hostname, it first checks its hosts file; if an entry is in there that matches the desired hostname, the IP of that entry is immediately returned. However, a server's hosts file does not determine the DNS lookups of any other computer; that's left for the DNS server to figure out.

Some certain environments will check the entire local IP netmask in search of a computer with a hostname that matches the requested one, but it isn't always guaranteed to work.

If the client is a Windows computer, you might have more luck if you enable the Samba service on the Ubuntu machine, and make sure that the Samba hostname is set to fileserver.

Comment: Good to hear! If you don't mind, please click the checkmark under the voting number to the left of this answer to mark it as accepted.

Comment: hmm.. i can't  maybe because this was migrated from stackoverflow??

Comment: No worries, it's not a big deal :) thanks for trying!